# видео RTSP/RTMP/RTMPS трансляция на вебсайт

Tags: wordpress, rtsp, rtmp, онлайн-трансляция

Подскажите пожалуйста, как и через чего реализовать видео трансляцию по протоколу RTSP/RTMP/RTMPS на Web сайте (WordPress)? Бесплатными средствами....

Comment: искал тоже как-то чем воспроизводить ртсп поток с камеры / сервера в браузере без плагинов - решения нет. кое-как еще работает VLC, и то не с каждым браузером.

Comment: Это печально...

Comment: Не судьба поискать в репо https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/RTSP/ ?

Comment: @SeVlad насколько я уже покапался, в итоге они не бесплатные... Либо работают как-то не так... Если я не прав, то буду рад узнать где именно)